# Edit page numbering from bottom middle position to right position and have it say "page 1", "page 2", etc

Tags: header-footer, numbering

I was wondering if it is possible to move the page numbering position to the lower right or upper right corner and have it write "page 1", "page 2", etc. Instead og "1", "2"?

I'm currently using `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

Comment: You can do that with `fancyhdr` or `titleps` (from the `titlesec` bundle).

Comment: @jubibanna did the answer below meet your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{Some Random Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rfoot{Page \thepage}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    Some random words.    
    \newpage
    Some random words on second page.
    
\end{document}
```